# Unable to find files with ssh and environment variables

Tags: tramp, find-file, bash, environment

I have installed `exec-path-from-shell` as well as included the following in my `init.el`

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

within my `~/.bash_profile` I have defined an environment variable called `SOLARIS` which stores an IP address.
I run the command `M-x exec-path-from-shell-copy-env (RET) SOLARIS (RET)` to 'import' the environment variable.
But when I run `C-x C-f /ssh:user@$SOLARIS:` it throws out the error:

```
Error running timerL (error "In 'Find Files' source: 'helm-find-files-get-candidates' 
(user-error \"Not a Tramp file name: \\\"/ssh:user@$SOLARIS:\\\"\")")
```

When I run the `find-file` command using the explicit IP address instead of the environment variable, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

There is no expansion of shell variables there, either before or after it looks for the TRAMP filename syntax.

I recommend configuring your ssh config file (`~/.ssh/config`) to have aliases that you can use. Something like, perhaps:

```
Host solaris
    Hostname w.x.y.z
```

Then, when you open the file `/ssh:user@solaris:…` in Emacs, ssh will use the correct ip address for the short host name 'solaris'. If you also specify the `IdentityFile` option, then it will automatically use the correct ssh key as well. That will save you time since you won't have to type in a password. You can shorten it even more by specifying the `User` option as well, so that you don't have to type your username every time.

Comment: thanks but ideally I am looking for a solution which allows me to carry over the `.emacs.d` to another machine, which might have different environmental variables

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a problem in helm, which doesn't expand environment variables. I have tried to reproduce the problem:

1. Download `exec-path-from-shell.el` from github (melpa doesn't work ATM)
2. `# emacs -Q -l ~/Downloads/exec-path-from-shell.el`
3. Evaluate `(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x)) (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))`. This results in `(("MANPATH" . "/usr/share/man:") ("PATH" . "/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"))`. No problem, I can use any environment variable for my test.
4. Evaluate `M-x exec-path-from-shell-copy-env (RET) MANPATH (RET)`.
5. Open the file `C-x C-f /ssh:user@$MANPATH:`. Obviously an error, but it tries to open `/ssh:user@/usr/share/man::` as expected.

I recommend to check, what helm does.

Comment: melpa works, I initially had problems connecting, turns out that milkbox is officially depreciated, I switched to `http://melpa.org/packages/` and it works, nonetheless thanks for the tip!

Comment: Does this mean that this answer answers the question satisfactorily? If so, can you please accept it?